# When updating layout handle how to call custom action from the block?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

When updating layout handle i need to call some function from block from which i am updating. I want to basically to set some menu links as active but no success with this code

```
    <customer_account_myact>
        <update handle="customer_account">
            </update>
            <reference name="left">
                <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
                    <action method="setActive"><path>customer/account/MyServices/</path></action>
                </block>
            </reference>
    </customer_account_myact>
```

When I do 'update handle="customer_account"', it renders the all links in left sidebar menu, but what i need is to make certain link "active" so i am trying to to refer to block to call the action from there.

This is all i want, but when i do so it breaks all stuff and no links are rendered.

If i can, I suppose it should be possible to re declare all the links via xml and calling the block method, but i believe that there should be an easier, and, more correct way of doing this, just to leave it as is, but calling the method from block?

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to create a new block rather than reference and existing one here?

Comment: when i do 'update handle="customer_account"' it renders the all links in left sidebar menu, but what i need is to make certain link "active" so i am trying to to refer to block to call the action from there. this is all i want, but when i do so it breaks all stuff and no links are rendered. as i can suppose it should be possible to redeclare all the links via xml and call the block method, but i beleive there should be easier, and, more correct way of doing this, just to leave it as is, but call the method from block? thanks!

Comment: @Anonymous please add the comment info to your question for readability

Answer (score 1):

It was just required to refer the layout reference name, instead of redeclaring a reference:

```
       <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
                <action method="setActive"><path>customer/account/MyAction/</path></action>
        </reference>
```